# Better way to model RATED relationship in neo4j movie graph database

Tags: neo4j

I want to know which is better approach to model `[:RATED]` relationship in movie database in Nneo4J? I can think of following two approaches:

[image]

Approach 1 feels more straighforward and somehow design academically more correct.
However, approach 1 requires n `(:Movie)` nodes. One might say that approach 2 looks more natural as graph can contain only one `(:Movie)` node for a particular movie ("The Matrix" in this case) which can exists regardless whether anyone rates it or not. However I feel it less comfortable  to store rating values on `[:RATED]` relationship. Is it correct looking in purely design perspective?

Also what if we are dealing with a node which does not represent an entity. For example bunch of cars replacing users in above image and accident replacing "The Matrix". In this case `(:Accident)` node may not exist by default, but only created when accident occurs. Also accident faced by two different cars are different instances of `(:Accident)` and have many attributes associated with them like time, place etc. In this case it makes more design sense to create separate `(:Accident)` node for each car whenever it encounters accident and have its properties associated with it instead of having single `(:Accident)` and have properties associated with relationships pointing from`(:Car)` to `(:Accident)`. But then it will create a lot of `(:Accident)` nodes. What will be best approach for this scenario in design perspective and performance perspective?

Summarizing:

1. Is approach 2 perfectly fine in design perspective? (Especially storing properties on relationships which might have been stored on nodes instead)
2. What are possible design, performance drawbacks of approach 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, whatever approach you choose to use should fit your use cases and queries.

Given your example, approach 2, using one Matrix :Movie node, is perfectly fine design given the use cases of tracking movie ratings. This is the same approach used in the Movie graph you can load up in Neo4j. Try that out, and note that the graph would be chaotic and difficult to query if there were multiple separate :Movie nodes for every single relationship to a :Movie.

You'll note that in approach 1, there is absolutely nothing different between each of the Matrix :Movie nodes. That's a strong indicator that you should be modeling the thing as a single node instead of multiple. It's also more difficult to query if you're using multiple nodes for the same thing, as the database can no longer use a single node as a starting point for the movie to get data based on relationships from it. Your queries about the movie itself also become slightly more complicated, in that you will need to add `LIMIT 1` when matching to the movie by name, otherwise the query will match to all the multiple Matrix movies, which could be in the thousands or more depending on how many ratings there are.

Even though some of the other queries you might use for this model are going to use similar Cypher, or even the same Cypher queries, you will be needlessly impacting db operations through this data model. Consider an average rating query. With a single Matrix :Movie node, it's a matter of matching on the single :Movie node (by indexed or unique name), then taking the average of all its relationships. With multiple Matrix :Movie nodes, your match will match on thousands (or more) redundant nodes, and for all of those nodes it will need to pull those relationships and average them together. That's a ton of db hits you didn't need to do.

Also, keep in mind the difficulty of using this approach when combining this for other use cases. For example, consider if we had to change your data model to include actors and directors, similar to the movie db you can import in neo4j. If we had multiple nodes for every single rating for every single movie, which node would we use when creating relationships between actors and directors and the movie they worked in? With that kind of data model, there are no good choices for modeling this kind of data efficiently or clearly.

Considering your second case, it makes sense to make a new :Accident node with each accident, with details of the accident in each node. If two or more cars in your db is involved in the same accident, then it makes sense to use the same accident node to represent the accident, and make relationships from the multiple cars to the same accident they were involved in. That saves you from duplicating data about the same accident instance, and clearly models the participants in the accident, along with any other related data that is associated with the accident. You could always store accident data specific to the car in question on the relationship between the car and the accident, such as the damage sustained, and whether the driver of the car was found at fault.

It should be clear in this data model that there should be separate :Accident nodes (unless, as mentioned, it's the same accident for multiple cars), as the data between accidents will differ, and requires you to capture them in separate nodes. This is far different than your movie data model, where it does not make sense to use multiple :Movie nodes for the same movie, since the data is all the same.

As for storing data in relationships, again that depends upon your data model, and what makes the most sense. For ratings, storing the rating on the relationship to the movie looks fine to me.

There are cases where you may consider creating intermediary nodes to store data on a node instead of a relationship. Consider an employment graph, with :Person and :Company nodes. You could model this simply with :WORKS_AT relationships between nodes, but you would need to store data about the employment on the relationship, such as hireDate, salary, jobTitle, etc. That might be fine...but you could always extract that into its own node, an :Employment node between a :Person and a :Company to hold that data. That could let us index those properties, making it easier to query :Persons for a :Company in order of hireDate, for example, which wouldn't be as efficient if the data was on the relationships, as you can't index on relationship properties.

EDIT

Concerning cardinality of nodes, when to use a single node instance vs multiple node instances, again, that's usually best answered as you answer the questions of "does this make logical sense for this data model" and "is this easy and efficient to query this data?"

The two cases you presented, for Matrix :Movie nodes and :Accident nodes, each demonstrate opposite cases for this.

A single Matrix :Movie node makes sense, I think it may be a stretch to find use cases which would require multiple copies of Matrix nodes.

However, if you had to model movie showings of The Matrix, then that might call for a :Showing node, of which there would be several (per time and per theater), but all of them referencing the same Matrix :Movie node. It's the same movie, but it has multiple showings.

For :Accidents, it makes sense to use multiple :Accident nodes, each one representing a particular instance of an accident. In many cases there will be only one :Car associated with a single :Accident node, a driver crashing into something without involving other drivers. In other cases, when it's a multi-car collision, then several cars are involved in the same :Accident, so you would have the :Accident node with the time and location and details, and relationships with the :Cars involved in that particular accident.

While it's possible to use a single :Accident node for ALL accidents, and have the details on the relationships, you'll quickly encounter problems with some of the likely queries you'll need to make. For example, how do you know which accidents were multi-car accidents, and which cars were involved? We would have to examine all relationships to the single :Accident node, and even then we'd have to do extra logic to figure out the associations. What if we wanted to order :Accidents by date? We can't use indexes on relationship properties, so again we have to touch on all relationships and inspect their properties and sort them all. What if we wanted to indicate location based on closest city to the accident, for fast lookup of accidents in certain cities? Again, we can't use indexes on relationship properties for fast lookup. If we already have :City nodes, we can't create relationships between the relevant :City node and the crash relationship, you need a node for that.

I could list more cases, but it's fairly clear that multiple :Accident nodes are needed per accident (again, sharing the node for :Cars involved in the same :Accident).

This is one of those cases where even if you missed it when thinking about if the data model makes sense, consideration about the kind of queries you want to make, and their efficiency, should push you toward a better means of modeling your data...in this case, using multiple :Accident nodes.

Comment: I am tempting to summarize this as follows: "when single node of type A is associated with multiple **but not all** nodes of type B and there is at least one property associated with node type A, we cannot have single instance of node type A across whole graph since if we decide to have single instance of node type A its property(ies) will get replicated on relationships from nodes of type B of a same group associated with single instance of node type A". Sounds tricky, but I feel its the final subtle reason. Am I right?

Comment: Hmm. That's a rather complex statement, I admit I'm having trouble parsing it. Personally I feel that you might be thinking a little too hard about this. With graph databases, common sense tends to have a strong influence on the data model. If an entity is logically the same, it makes sense to have a single instance of that entity (such as a Matrix :Movie node, or the same :Accident instance in which multiple :Cars were involved).

Comment: That said, your queries and your data will also have a strong impact on how you tweak your data model. Properties on relationships are fine, and in some of the cases you've mentioned, it makes sense. That said, property-heavy relationships, as well as relationships which seem to need to reference an additional node, may be good candidates for refactoring into an intermediary node. You should always be asking yourself 'does this make sense at a high level' and 'does this allow fast and easy querying' as you model your data. There are always tradeoffs of course, but it's good to be mindful.

Comment: Nope I guess that's not all there is: "if entity is logically same, have single instance across graph". If there are multiple logical instances of nodetype A and if each of them is going to be associated with exactly one instance of nodetype B, then also we can have single instance of nodetype A across whole graph with all A's property's stored on relationship from corresponding instance of nodetype B to nodetype A. Considering only one car is involved in any accident will immitate this case, though unreal. (continued to next comment...)

Comment: Somewhat real example: only one `(:Buffer)` node can be associated with corresponding instance of `(:OverflowEvent)` node. We can have single `(:OverflowEvent)` node across whole graph (**even though these are logically different events**) with properties of overflow event stored on the relationship from corresponding `(:Buffer)` node to `(:OverflowEvent)` node.So why I was saying: "its also important to have **some (not all)** nodetype A (here`(:Buffer)`) instances associated with **same single** nodetype B (here`(:OverflowEvent)`) instance". Hope I am clear this time. Am I correct with this?

Comment: I don't think you can depend upon an ironclad rule for this, your use cases for queries and their efficiency will likely push you in the right direction for how to model your data. I edited my answer to discuss this a bit more. In general, though, property-heavy relationships can often be a strong indicator that you may need to change your model, especially if there are many relationships, and you need fast queries for calculating relationship property values or looking up relationships by those properties.